# Derivatives with quantities held constant

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, physics, partial-derivative, statistical-mechanics

I am running into the following notation:

$$\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_w$$

which is stated to be "the partial derivative of $x$ with respect to $y$ at constant values of $w$" and where

$$x=x(y,w).$$

(I see this in physics literature, for example when dealing with entropy and adiabaticity.)

I am just wondering how I can calculate this kind of quantity. I have quantities $x,y,w$ at times $t-1, t, t+1$ etc and want to calculate that derivative at time $t$. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a function $x = x(y, \ldots)$ so your expression requires you to compute
$$
f(y, \ldots) = \frac{\partial x}{\partial y}
$$
and then evaluate $f(w, \ldots)$. I think the corresponding notation in mathematics books would be
$$
\left. \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \right|_{y=w}
$$

Comment: I think that 'w' may not be a constant for y but some other constant.  But I agree with everything else.  The notation is weird.

Comment: I think you are on the right track that $x=x(y,...)$ however $w$ is a constant that is different from $y$, not to be subbed in for $y$ as @lordoftheshadows indicated.